# Why isnt my ajax response returning anything?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an ajax request where I register a user (wordpress). I want the user id to be sent back to the success response, but it just shows undefined, or blank in the case below:

```
$(document).on('submit', '.register_user_form', function(event){
event.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
          action: 'register_user_form',
          currentUserName: $("#First_Name").val() + " " + $("#Last_Name").val(),
          currentUserEmail: $("#email").val(),
          currentUserPassword: $("#password").val(),
        },
        success: function(res) {
          console.log(res);
        }
      });

});
```

```
PHP function (wordpress):
function register_user_form() {
    $user_login = $_POST['currentUserName'];
    $user_email = $_POST['currentUserEmail'];
    $user_pass = $_POST['currentUserPassword'];
    $userdata = compact( 'user_login', 'user_email', 'user_pass' );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user($userdata);

    echo 'this doesnt get returned';

    wp_die();

}
add_action('wp_ajax_register_user_form', 'register_user_form');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_register_user_form', 'register_user_form');
```

I have tried `echo json_encode('');` but that doesn't work either. fyi - the user does get registered

Comment: should prob use `wp_send_json('this doesnt get returned')`, instead

Comment: thanks but no joy with wp_send_json @LawrenceCherone

Comment: try removing `dataType: 'html'`, debug if its the jquery or wp by looking at network tab to see the response, dataType: 'html' wont work with Content-type: application/json if wp is responding with it, etc

Comment: thanks @LawrenceCherone, but removing dataType didnt do anything either. network tab just showing 'this response request has no data available'

Comment: Replace  echo 'this doesnt get returned'; with return  'this doesnt get returned';

Comment: thanks @Grumpy, unfortunately return just brings back an empty value - not undefined.